# MVC multiple file download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to ask a suggestion about a project I'm following. I need to create an action inside an MVC controller that let me download a series of images directly and not by compressing them inside a zip archive. I tried to achieve that by calling a download function inside the action, like this:

```
foreach(var image in images){
    var imageFilename = image.filename;
    var imageName = image.text;
    var mimeType = image.type;
    DownloadFile(imageFilename, imageName, mimeType);
}
```

Setting download file as

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(string imageFilename, string imageName, string mimeType){
     return File(imageFilename, imageName, mimeType);
}
```

But this not works. Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed on this to avoid zip archive? Or is the only suitable method for this problem?

Comment: This is not how the web works... If you want a single response - your best bet would be to return a custom model from the server-side, containing all bytes for the files, then writing a custom disposition for the client-side that will eventually not work on most browsers... The correct way of doing this is for the files to be zipped or for the files to be extracted by multiple requests.

Comment: Thank you very much Samuil. Perfectly clear.